# Prepending a timestamp to each line of output from a command

Tags: shell, timestamps

I wish to prepend a timestamp to each line of output from a command. For example:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

would become

```
[2011-12-13 12:20:38] foo
[2011-12-13 12:21:32] bar
[2011-12-13 12:22:20] baz
```

...where the time being prefixed is the time at which the line was printed. How can I achieve this?

Comment: [Is there a Unix utility to prepend timestamps to stdin?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21564/95735)

Answer (score 551, accepted):

[moreutils](http://kitenet.net/%7Ejoey/code/moreutils/) includes `ts` which does this quite nicely:

`command | ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]'`

It eliminates the need for a loop too, every line of output will have a timestamp put on it.

```
$ echo -e "foo\nbar\nbaz" | ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]'
[2011-12-13 22:07:03] foo
[2011-12-13 22:07:03] bar
[2011-12-13 22:07:03] baz
```

You want to know when that server came back up you restarted? Just run `ping | ts` , problem solved :D.

**Note**: Use `[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%.S]` for microsecond precision.

Comment: How have I not known about this?!?!?! This complements tail -f amazingly! `tail -f /tmp/script.results.txt | ts`

Comment: What about in cygwin?  Is there something similar?  It doesn't appear Joey's moreutils are there.

Comment: if I don't have ts command, what should I use?

Comment: If it's not working, try redirecting stderr to stdout e.g. `ssh -v 127.0.0.1 2>&1 | ts`

Comment: Note that if you want fractional seconds, use "%.S". See `man ts`.

Comment: Install by doing `sudo apt install moreutils` on Debian and `yum install moreutils` on Fedora.

Comment: It's written in perl, so it should be portable

Comment: I think pointing out the parameter `-s` is useful. As that displays the runtime of the command. I personally like using both `ts` and `ts -s` at the same time. Looks something like this: `command | ts -s '(%H:%M:%.S)]' | ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`. This prepends the log lines like this: `[2018-12-04 08:31:00 (00:26:28.267126)] Hai <3`

Comment: I tried to install this on Amazon Linux 2 by enabling a repo `sudo yum --enablerepo epel install moreutils` however, it wasn't possible to install ts after this action.

Comment: Can I make it part of base profile and every output will have timestamp prepanded to it by default?

Comment: Thank you! `ts '[%.T]'` worked best for me since it's short and has fractional seconds, e.g. `[19:00:12.337762]`.

Comment: There is an issue with this on my system, which seems to be related to buffering. ts outputs stuff in chunks all with the same timestamp. ts does not seem to unbuffer on new lines. Instead there seems to be a buffer of at least several kB.

Comment: doesn't work with cron for me. `perl` works from cron, but `ts` isn't. I don't know how to debug

Comment: Just to let people know, `%Y-%m-%d` can be shortened to `%F` and `%H:%M:%S` can be shortened to `%T`.  So `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` can be written more succinctly as `%F %T` (which is also much easier to type).

Comment: Mac users - To install `ts` in mac, run `brew install moreutils`.

Answer (score 191):

Firstly, if you are expecting these timestamps to actually represent an event, bear in mind that since many programs perform line buffering (some more aggressively than others), it is important to think of this as close to the time that the original line would have been printed rather than a timestamp of an action taking place.

You may also want to check that your command doesn't already have an inbuilt feature dedicated to doing this. As an example, `ping -D` exists in some `ping` versions, and prints the time since the Unix epoch before each line. If your command does not contain its own method, however, there are a few methods and tools that can be employed, amongst others:

### POSIX shell

Bear in mind that since many shells store their strings internally as cstrings, if the input contains the null character (`\0`), it may cause the line to end prematurely.

```
command | while IFS= read -r line; do printf '[%s] %s\n' "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')" "$line"; done
```

### GNU awk

```
command | gawk '{ print strftime("[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]"), $0 }'
```

### Perl

```
command | perl -pe 'use POSIX strftime; print strftime "[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S] ", localtime'
```

### Python

```
command | python -c 'import sys,time;sys.stdout.write("".join(( " ".join((time.strftime("[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]", time.localtime()), line)) for line in sys.stdin )))'
```

### Ruby

```
command | ruby -pe 'print Time.now.strftime("[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S] ")'
```

Comment: One problem here is that many programs turn on even more output buffering when their stdout is a pipe instead of the terminal.

Comment: @cjm - True. Some output buffering can be alleviated by using `stdbuf -o 0`, but if the program is manually handling its output buffering, it won't help (unless there is an option to disable/reduce the size of the output buffer).

Comment: For python, you can disable line buffering with `python -u`

Comment: @Bwmat No. `... for x in sys.stdin` iterates over lines without buffering them all into memory first.

Comment: Do this and you get buffering... for a in 1 1 1 1 1; do sleep 1; echo; done | python -c 'import sys,time;sys.stdout.write("".join(( " ".join((time.strftime("[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]", time.gmtime()), line)) for line in sys.stdin )))'

Comment: could we somehow alleviate the posix shell null-terminated string problem by using a fixed length string? If so, then how to modify the script above?

Comment: Along the lines of the buffering related comments above: when using a multi-stage pipeline to pre-filter the output with grep, the `--line-buffered` option is needed to make this work.

Comment: Just to let people know, `%Y-%m-%d` can be shortened to `%F` and `%H:%M:%S` can be shortened to `%T`.  So `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` can be written more succinctly as `%F %T` (which is also much easier to type).

Answer (score 70):

For a line-by-line delta measurement, try [gnomon](https://github.com/paypal/gnomon).

> It is a command line utility, a bit like moreutils's ts, to prepend timestamp information to the standard output of another command. Useful for long-running processes where you'd like a historical record of what's taking so long.
>
> Piping anything to gnomon will prepend a timestamp to each line, indicating how long that line was the last line in the buffer--that is, how long it took the next line to appear. By default, gnomon will display the seconds elapsed between each line, but that is configurable.

[image: gnomon demo]

Comment: Looks like a great alternative to `ts` when using live processes. While `ts` is better suited for non-interactive processes.

Answer (score 12):

I would have preferred to comment above but I can't, reputationally. Anyway, the Perl sample above can be unbuffered as follows:

```
command | perl -pe 'use POSIX strftime; 
                    $|=1; 
                    select((select(STDERR), $| = 1)[0]);
                    print strftime "[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S] ", localtime'
```

The first '$|' unbuffers STDOUT. The second one sets stderr as the current default output channel and unbuffers it. Since select returns the original setting of $|, by wrapping the select inside a select, we also reset $| to its default, STDOUT.

And yes, you can cut 'n paste as is. I multi-lined it for legibility.

And if you really want to get precise (and you have [Time::Hires](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::HiRes) installed):

```
command | perl -pe 'use POSIX strftime; use Time::HiRes gettimeofday;
                    $|=1; 
                    select((select(STDERR), $| = 1)[0]);
                    ($s,$ms)=gettimeofday();
                    $ms=substr(q(000000) . $ms,-6);
                    print strftime "[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.$ms]", localtime($s)'
```

Comment: Works like a charm, without having to install any non-standard packages.

Answer (score 11):

Shameless plug for something I just wrote to solve this exact problem: [`ets`](https://github.com/zmwangx/ets#readme), written in Go.

[image: demo]

You can find a lot of usage examples on the project page.

The notable difference from existing answers and similar offerings is that `ets` is designed to run your command for you, in a pty (pseudo tty) — that is to say, simulating your command running natively in a tty. Compared to piping command output into e.g. `ts`, this makes timestamping mostly transparent, and solves a bunch of issues of piping:

- Some programs aggressively buffer when writing to a pipe, so you see no output and then a whole bunch of output (yeah, you can stdbuf them, you can even wrap stdbuf and ts in an alias/function, but wouldn't it be better if things work out of the box);
- Some programs disable color and/or interactivity when writing to a pipe;
- Exit status is gone unless you turned on pipefail; etc.

Commands can be directly exec'ed, meaning you can simply prepend `ets` to your existing command line, or they can be shell commands (as shown in the gif above). Of course, if you want to pipe output in, `ets` can do that too.

`ets` supports the same timestamp modes as moreutils `ts`: absolute time mode, elapsed time mode, and incremental time mode. It uses saner defaults (e.g. monotonic clock is always used for elapsed/incremental timestamps) and has additional support for custom time zones. There's a detailed comparison [here](https://github.com/zmwangx/ets#comparison-to-moreutils-ts).

Again, https://github.com/zmwangx/ets. Give it a spin, report bugs, etc.

Answer (score 9):

Most of answers suggest to use `date`, but it's slow enough. If your bash version is greater than 4.2.0 it's better to use `printf` instead, it's a bash builtin.
If you need to support legacy bash versions you can create `log` function depends on bash version:

```
TIMESTAMP_FORMAT='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'
# Bash version in numbers like 4003046, where 4 is major version, 003 is minor, 046 is subminor.
printf -v BV '%d%03d%03d' ${BASH_VERSINFO[0]} ${BASH_VERSINFO[1]} ${BASH_VERSINFO[2]}
if ((BV > 4002000)); then
log() {
    ## Fast (builtin) but sec is min sample for most implementations
    printf "%(${TIMESTAMP_FORMAT})T %5d %s\n" '-1' $$ "$*"  # %b convert escapes, %s print as is
}
else
log() {
    ## Slow (subshell, date) but support nanoseconds and legacy bash versions
    echo "$(date +"${TIMESTAMP_FORMAT}") $$ $*"
}
fi
```

See speed differences:

```
user@host:~$time for i in {1..10000}; do printf "%(${TIMESTAMP_FORMAT})T %s\n" '-1' "Some text" >/dev/null; done

real    0m0.410s
user    0m0.272s
sys     0m0.096s
user@host:~$time for i in {1..10000}; do echo "$(date +"${TIMESTAMP_FORMAT}") Some text" >/dev/null; done

real    0m27.377s
user    0m1.404s
sys     0m5.432s
```

UPD: instead of `$(date +"${TIMESTAMP_FORMAT}")` it's better to use `$(exec date +"${TIMESTAMP_FORMAT}")` or even `$(exec -c date +"${TIMESTAMP_FORMAT}")` too speedup execution.

UPD2: bash 5 provides `EPOCHREALTIME` variable for microseconds granularity, you can use it by this command (about 30% slower than seconds only):
`printf "%(${TIMESTAMP_FORMAT})T.%s %5d %s\n" ${EPOCHREALTIME/./ } $$ "$*"`

Comment: This answer is very underrated!
Particularly nice to show the relative performance impact.

Comment: Excellent suggestion, but unfortunately date does not provide sub-second resolution, which is a requirement in my case

Comment: With bash 5.0+ you can use this command: `printf "%(${TIMESTAMP_FORMAT})T.%s %5d %s\n" ${EPOCHREALTIME/./ } $$ "$*"`

Answer (score 8):

[Ryan's post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/295787/52959) does provide an interesting idea, however,  it fails in several regards. While testing with `tail -f /var/log/syslog | xargs -L 1 echo $(date +'[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]') $1`  , I noticed that timestamp stays the same even if `stdout` comes later with difference in seconds apart. Consider this output:

```
[2016-07-14 01:44:25] Jul 14 01:44:32 eagle dhclient[16091]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.78 on wlan7 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x411b8c21)
[2016-07-14 01:44:25] Jul 14 01:44:34 eagle avahi-daemon[740]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan7.IPv6 with address fe80::d253:49ff:fe3d:53fd.
[2016-07-14 01:44:25] Jul 14 01:44:34 eagle avahi-daemon[740]: New relevant interface wlan7.IPv6 for mDNS.
```

My proposed solution is similar, however provides proper time-stamping and uses somewhat more portable `printf` rather than `echo`

```
| xargs -L 1 bash  -c 'printf "[%s] %s\n" "$(date +%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M:%S )" "$*" ' bash
```

Why `bash -c '...' bash` ? Because due to `-c` option, first argument gets assigned to `$0` and won't show up in the output. Consult your shell's manual page for the proper description of `-c`

Testing this solution with `tail -f /var/log/syslog` and (as  you probably could guess) disconnecting and reconnecting to my wifi, has shown the proper time-stamping provided by both `date` and `syslog` messages

Bash could be replaced by any bourne-like shell, could be done with either `ksh` or `dash` , at least those that have `-c` option.

#### Potential issues:

The solution requires having `xargs` ,which is available on POSIX compliant systems, so most Unix-like systems should be covered. Obviously won't work if your system is non-POSIX compliant or doesn't have `GNU findutils`

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with `date` and `xargs`:

```
... | xargs -L 1 echo `date +'[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]'` $1
```

### Explanation:

`xargs -L 1` tells xargs to run the proceeding command for every 1 line of input, and it passes in the first line as it does so. `` echo `date +'[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]'` $1 `` basically echoes the date with the input argument at the end of it

Comment: The solution is close, but doesn't timestamp properly when it comes to output separated by long periods of time. Also , you're using backticks and haven't quoted `$1` . That's not good style. Always quote the variables. In addition, you're using `echo` , which is not portable . It's alright, but may not properly work on some systems.

Comment: After testing this, it appears you're absolutely right... do you know of any way to make `date` get reevaluated every line, or is it pretty much hopeless?

Answer (score 3):

If you are working in bash, put this near the start of your script

```
exec &> >( ts '%Y-%m-%d.%H%M.%.S ' )  # prepend a timestamp to all output
```

Or, for extra credit, output to log file via:

```
script_name=foobar
log_file=$( printf "/tmp/${script_name}-%(%Y-%m-%d)T.%(%H%M%S)T.log" -1 )
echo "note: redirecting output to [${log_file}]"
exec &> >( ts '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%.S ' > ${log_file} )
```

to output to both console and log file:

```
script_name=foobar
log_file=$( printf "/tmp/${script_name}-%(%Y-%m-%d)T.%(%H%M%S)T.log" -1 )
exec &> >( ts '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%.S ' | tee ${log_file} )
```

The main advantages of doing this are to separate the logging from everything else, not cluttering the body of the script by piping to `tee` or similar on every command, and not having to write custom logging functions and sticking to plain old `echo` and `printf`.

The `ts` program is found in the `moreutils` package, which should be readily available under any reasonably sane administration regime. :-)

Comment: An explanation of, or link to relevant docs for, the usage of `exec &> >(...)` would really improve this answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Most of these answers suck for measuring performance. AWK can't show milliseconds. Ruby and Python are slow af. Also all of them show the absolute time when you'd really want relative times.

I figured someone would probably have written a decent solution in Rust, and they have!

**[rtts](https://github.com/freaky/rtss)**

You can pipe into it:

```
-% cargo build --release 2>&1 | rtss
 274.1ms  274.1ms |    Compiling libc v0.2.40
   1.50s    1.22s |    Compiling memchr v2.0.1
   2.28s  780.8ms |    Compiling rtss v0.5.0 (file:///home/freaky/code/rtss)
   5.18s    2.90s |     Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 5.17 secs
   5.18s    exit code: 0
```

Or wrap a command:

```
-% rtss sh -c "echo foo; echo bar; sleep 1; echo moo >&2; sleep 1; echo baz; exit 64"
   1.7ms    1.7ms | foo
   1.7ms          | bar
   1.00s    1.00s # moo
   2.03s    2.03s | baz
   2.03s    exit code: 64
zsh: exit 64    rtss sh -c

-% rtss sh -c "echo foo; echo bar; sleep 1; echo moo >&2; sleep 1; echo baz; exit 64" 2>/dev/null
   1.9ms    1.9ms | foo
   1.9ms          | bar
   2.05s    2.04s | baz
   2.05s    exit code: 64
zsh: exit 64    rtss sh -c  2> /dev/null
```

It also shows you the time taken for each line (the second column) which is quite helpful.

It also works for both stderr and stdout.

Unfortunately they haven't set up CI to build binaries, but installing Rust programs is easy if you already have Rust installed:

```
cargo install rtss
```

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done using `logger`, usually shipped with most distros I would assume:

```
host ~ # echo sup | logger --no-act -s
<13>Feb 11 15:59:00 root: sup
```

Answer (score 0):

### Prefix output

```bash
{
  echo foo
  sleep 1
  echo bar >&2
} \
   > >(sed "s/^/$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') [INF] /") \
  2> >(sed "s/^/$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') [ERR] /" >&2)
```

### Prefix output and redirect to a log file

Redirect script to `test.log` file:

```bash
{
  echo foo
  sleep 1
  echo bar >&2
} \
   > test.log \
  2>&1 \
   > >(sed "s/^/$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') [INF] /") \
  2> >(sed "s/^/$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') [ERR] /" >&2)
```

Answer (score -3):

This is a small tool implemented in C:

```
/*
 * Redirect stdin to stdout, prepending a millisecond-precision
 * Unix timestamp to each line.
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   char *line = NULL;
   size_t linecap = 0;
   ssize_t linelen;
   struct timeval tv;

   while ((linelen = getline(&line, &linecap, stdin)) > 0) {
      gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
      fprintf(stdout, "%lu ", tv.tv_sec*1000 + tv.tv_usec/1000);
      fwrite(line, linelen, 1, stdout);
   }
}
```

Paste the above code into a .c file. I call mine `tsms.c`. Then

`gcc -o tsms tsms.c`

and then

`command | tsms`

and you can be a big boy too.