# Timestamp ts not working with thinkfan

Tags: shell, timestamps, thinkpad

I wanted the output of `thinkfan -n` output with a timestamp next to it so I can later analyse the patterns, and found this question: [Prepending a timestamp to each line of output from a command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26728/51034), which had a seemingly good answer to this problem, namely using:

`thinkfan -n | ts`

Except it doesn't work. `ts` works fine with all other programs I tried, just not with `thinkfan`. Why doesn't it work with `thinkfan`? Is there some way to get this to work?

Comment: Does `thinkfan -n 2>&1 | ts` work? (or `thinkfan -n |& ts` if you've got a new-enough bash)

Comment: @derobert yes, it does... stupid me :D should have thought of that.

Comment: I'll add an answer, then... At least it'll leave a Google artifact for the next person who's having an "is it plugged in?" day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two output streams from a program—standard output and standard error. `|` redirects standard output, leaving standard error going straight to your terminal.

You can redirect both:

```shell
thinkfan -n 2>&1 | ts    # should work everywhere
thinkfan -n |& ts        # newer versions of bash, maybe other shells
```