# POSIX Shell: Output to log and prepend lines with timestamps using a function

Tags: shell-script, shell, logs, io-redirection, posix

I would like a shell script to have all it's output for `stdout` and `stderr` logged to an external file with timestamps prepended to each line (plus a few extra items), without changing how the script is called.  The output redirection should happen within the script itself.  I also should not have to change any existing code in the script or pipe commands individually. Ideally I would only have to add a few lines to the script.

Using these two answers:

- [Log entirety of bash script and prepend timestamp to each line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/550979/log-entirety-of-bash-script-and-prepend-timestamp-to-each-line)
- [Prepending a timestamp to each line of output from a command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26728/prepending-a-timestamp-to-each-line-of-output-from-a-command/26729#26729)

I got to a point where it's working on Bash

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

CUSTOM_PREFIX1="FancyScript"
CUSTOM_PREFIX2="SomeRunID_12-3-4.5"
LOG_FILE="/var/log/script.log"

touch $LOG_FILE
exec 1>> >(while IFS= read -r line; do printf '[%s] %s %s: %s\n' "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')" "${CUSTOM_PREFIX1}" "${CUSTOM_PREFIX2}" "${line}"; done >> "${LOG_FILE}")
exec 2>&1

# Script continues...
d
echo "Hello"
```

Running the script above produces no output and the following log file:

```
# cat /var/log/script.log

[2022-02-23 03:11:45] FancyScript SomeRunID_12-3-4.5: Development/shell_log.sh: line 12: d: command not found
[2022-02-23 03:11:45] FancyScript SomeRunID_12-3-4.5: Hello
```

So far so good, but I want to change two things.

1. Make it work in POSIX shell (`sh`) and not depend on Bash.  Regular `sh` doesn't like `exec 1>> >(...)`
2. Instead of that long sub process `(while IFS= read ....)` I want to pipe it to a function within the script itself.  Something like `pipe_log() {...}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [`logger`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/logger.html) is specifically written for this: writing to the syslog files.

See the `logger(1)` manual (`man logger`) and the link to the POSIX specification for that utility above for details.

Comment: This (`logger`) does the job perfectly.  As a nice bonus I can use the OS's `syslog` to further manage it.

Answer (score 0):

The most *advanced* text processing utilities in the Unix toolchest are `ex`/`vi`, `awk` and `m4`, all from the 70s. None of them have time formatting abilities (though with POSIX `awk`, you can get the epoch time via `srand()`, and several implementations of awk or vi have time formatting abilities as extensions).

`perl`, from the mid-80s however is quite ubiquitous and POSIX didn't have to be involved with its standardisation given that there's only one implementation of it.

So you can always wrap your `sh` script in:

```
{

  your-script here

} 2>&1 | perl -MPOSIX -pse '
  $_ = strftime("[%Y-%m-%dT%T%z]", localtime) . " $prefix$_"
  ' -- '-|=1' "-prefix=$CUSTOM_PREFIX" >> /path/to/file.log
```

To timestamp every line.

Note the `%z` for those timestamps to be unambiguous and post-processable.

Comment: Any non-syslog native tool used to try to write to syslog will utimately corrupt the file.

Comment: @JdeHaan there's no mention of syslog in the question.

Answer (score -1):

The `logger` I mentioned above is intended for the older syslogging environments. On newer, systemd based systems, the `systemd-cat` utility is more appropriate:

```
echo 'my message' | systemd-cat -p info -t /path/to/script/executing/this
```

Comment: That is not about age. `systemd` is Linux-specific in any case.