# How Can I Add Dates To Nohup Log Files Lines

Tags: logs, nohup

I'm running python on my server. I want to add date and time info to my nohup log file's lines.

Log file content similar to what I want to do (inside log file):

```
09/09/2023 07:13 Traceback (most recent call last):
09/09/2023 07:13 //Some Error
09/09/2023 07:13 //Error...
```

Is it possible to do this? So how?

Comment: Edit your code to send to STDOUT the way you want (with timestamp)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prepending a timestamp to each line of output from a command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26728/prepending-a-timestamp-to-each-line-of-output-from-a-command)

Answer (score 0):

Although not a very perfect solution, I did something like this. I created a .sh file and added this codes.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Output File
output_file="nohup_output"

nohup command > "$output_file" 2>&1 &

while true
do

    if tail -n 1 "$output_file" | grep -qF "$current_datetime"; then
        sleep 1
    else
        tail -n 0 -f "$output_file" | while read -r line; do
    current_datetime=$(date +"[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]")
    echo "$current_datetime $line"
    truncate -s 0 nohup_output # To delete inside the nohup_output file
    done >> "$output_file.log"
    fi
done
```

In this way, I got printouts containing the date and time as I wanted.