# rsync takes long time to start

Tags: linux, rsync

I'm running on Ubuntu 18.04 and the rsync command takes a long time to start. Given a file to transfer of 0 byte, it still takes more than 5 seconds to transfer.

Version of rsync: 3.1.2

```
time rsync rsync://192.168.0.105/small_file test
real    0m5.145s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.003s
```

I've checked:

- testing different options of rsync
- using another Ubuntu 18.04 with same version of rsync: the transfer takes less than 100ms
- using ssh, ping or scp to test if the network is slow: nothing wrong
- the DNS resolution delay is ok
- ram & cpu are ok

I'm running out of ideas to check and the verbose mode (-v) is not helpfull

Any idea of what the problem could be ? Or how I could debug it ?

Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried running with `-vvv` to see if more debug information shows you *where* the slowdown happens? Can you try using `ssh` as the medium for the sync rather than the `rsync` protocol itself?

Comment: The '5 seconds' delay sounds to me like there's a DNS lookup timing out somewhere.

Comment: -vvv has the exact same output on the server where it's slow and on the server where it's fast :(

Comment: Regarding the DNS, yes, I thought the same but I'm using the IP address directly and when I ping it, it works directly with no delay

Comment: With ssh it's working like a charm

Comment: I know you're using the IP address, but it may be that the receiving `rsync` host is attempting a DNS lookup either for logging purposes or to verify a whitelist.

Comment: Ah yes, good idea ! How can I test this hypothesis ?

Comment: Check logs on the other end. If rsync or rhost is running as a daemon it should be logging *something*.

Comment: Alternately, you can just use ssh as the transfer mode and not have to worry about it at all -- more secure anyway.

Comment: @JulienGreard the `-vvv` may provide the same output, but you can probably see between which lines the lag appears, and that might give you some hint. Start by [prepending timestamp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26728/273579) to your `rsync` commands, see between each lines there's the largest gap, it might direct you to some lead.

Comment: That was it thx @Shadur !! https://superuser.com/questions/198516/rsync-hangs-with-message-name-lookup-failed-for-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-no-address-ass. I had a "name lookup failed for" line in syslog, I changed the options in the config of rsync daemon and i worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by setting the `reverse lookup` settings to `no` in the rsync daemon.

Comment: This indicates that the _problem_ has to do with DNS configuration.  What you did was to work around the problem, without actually solving it, IMHO.

Comment: True, but we're fine with the workaround