Timestamp to each line of output (after finish command, how make view, when i input next command?)
In Terminal, i have see, when finish command, i view, when i input next command

I use this solution
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/622928/675422
exec &> >( ts '%Y-%m-%d %H%M.%.S ' )  # prepend a timestamp to all output
But after finish command, i do not view, when i input next command


Possible or not very-very need make, after finish command, i view, when i input next command
See screnshot

Thank You!

this technique, using exec &>..., is meant to be put into a shell script, not run interactively. Inside a shell script, exec replaces the shell script with the command that follows it, and when the shell script is done, the exec is also done. In an interactive terminal (at the command prompt), if you run exec, then when command ends, then your interactive login also ends. If you can put your commands in a shell script, then this solution will work for you. If you want timestamps on all output, you'll need a different solution.

welcome to U&L, please don't post picture, your sampl ecould be copy/pasted. Is your question about missing time stamp in prompt ?

I have view, when finished command, when i input next command

Despite my desire to see if I can help, I do not understand what you want to say. The words you put together are very far from forming sentences that grammatically make sense. May I kindly recommend either to ask for someone's help who speaks decent English to phrase your question, or to ask on a forum of your native language?
